# keep getting value error when filtering a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have a dataframe that I want to filter but keep getting a value error. I am using a specific api.

```
df= mc.load_batch("my_path")

rows_keep = [df.iloc[:9].uuid]

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.uuid not in rows_keep:
        df.caiman.remove_item(row.uuid)
```

I am getting a value error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Anyone who can help?

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.